# How to allow https://* in csp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-security-policy

So I am using CSP for my website, but I am running into an issue when it comes to my img-src header, I am using NodeJS, and Express to program my website, in which this website is for my Discord Bot, and well I am wanting to take the time to revamp the website, but now I am stuck.

======

So, I am using the following code for my headers:

```js
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-irregular-whitespace
                ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
                'default-src': ['\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'self\'', '\'https://*\'', '\'http://*\''],
                'script-src': ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*'],
                'img-src': ['\'self\'', '\'https://*\'', '\'http://*\''],
            },
        })
    );
```

====

And the error I get (For both Default and Img):

Couldn't Parse unknown Host: https://*

Couldn't Parse unknown Host: http://*

`Content Security Policy: Couldn’t parse invalid host 'https://*'`

`Content Security Policy: Couldn’t parse invalid host 'http://*'`

====

Thank you in advance for the help.

If anyone would like to check out the website for any sort of Idea of what I am trying to do, the link is https://therpbot.xyz/, and I am trying to get image links from discord.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow https without specifying a domain, then just use "https" without the colon, slashes or star, like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: "default-src https:; script-src https; img-src https"
```

[edit]: for default-src, include the colon...

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hosts like `'https://*'` are really invalid, because host-sources should not be a single quoted.

Remove one pair single quotes around `'\'https://*\''`, `'\'http://*\''`:

```
app.use(
        helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
            directives: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-irregular-whitespace
                ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
                'default-src': ['\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'self\'', 'https://*', 'http://*'],
                'script-src': ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-inline\'', '\'unsafe-eval\'', '*'],
                'img-src': ['\'self\'', 'https://*', 'http://*'],
            },
        })
    );
```